# Averaging over columns while ignoring zero entries

Tags: list-manipulation

I have:

```
list = {{1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 9}, {4, 0, 3, 5, 0, 2, 0}, 
        {1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4, 0}}
```

I want to calculate the average but without considering the 0s.

The result should be:

```
result = Array[0 &, Last@Dimensions@list];

n = Length@result;

Do[
  array = list[[All, i]];
  total = Total[array];
  cnt = Count[array, 0];

  If[Length@array - cnt > 0,
   result[[i]] = total/(Length@array - cnt),
   result[[i]] = 0
   ];,
  {i, 1, n}
  ];

result // N

{2., 3., 3., 4., 4., 3., 9.}
```

How can I replace the `Do` loop?

Comment: `Mean /@ DeleteCases[Transpose@list, 0, All]`

Comment: Thank you for the solution.

Comment: You’re welcome. I’ve added an answer since this solution works for you

Comment: I'm not at a computer right now, so please try `Total[list]/Total[Unitize[list]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Well, that is clever! Cool trick :-)

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive's answer is very APL-ish!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm posting this as a CW answer, so J.M.'s very nice answer, made in a comment above, gets recorded as a real answer.

```
list = {{1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 9}, {4, 0, 3, 5, 0, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4, 0}};
Total[list]/Total[Unitize[list]]
```

> `{2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 9}`

#### Update

As J.M. points out in a comment below, there is more robust formulation that handles the cases where one or mort columns contain all zeros.

```
list = {{1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 3, 5, 0, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4, 0}};
 Total[list]/(Total[Unitize[list]] /. 0 -> 1)
```

> ```
> {2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 0}
> ```

Comment: This produces an error for: `list = {{1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 3, 5, 0, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 
   4, 0}}`

Comment: @lio, change the denominator to `(Total[Unitize[list]] /. 0 -> 1)`.

Answer (score 8):

```
Mean /@ DeleteCases[Transpose@list, 0, All]
```

> {2,3,3,4,4,3,9}

Comment: This produces an error for: `list = {{1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 3, 5, 0, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 
   4, 0}}`

Comment: @lio, It does not produce an error. It just returns `Mean[{}]` in the case that all entries are zero. What result would you expect in that case?

Comment: I think the OP expects `{2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 0}` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[means]
means = Mean[#["NonzeroValues"] /. {} -> {0}] & /@ SparseArray[Transpose[#]] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
list1 = {{1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 9}, {4, 0, 3, 5, 0, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 2, 2, 2,  4, 0}};
means @ list1
```

> {2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 9}

```
list2 = {{1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 3, 5, 0, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 2, 2, 2,  4, 0}};
means @ list2
```

> {2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 0}